# Java Annotation: On property or on method? What the difference

Tags: java, annotations

Hibernate Search, Hibernate, Struts2... I see more examples... In same examples I see the annotation on the field.. Other on the get/set method..  There are differences? Or is casual..

I hope that is not a stupid question!

Saluti!

Luigi

Comment: The annotation goes on the field, method, class, constructor, parameter it is annotating. Its like a comment which it can be used at runtime.  You can comment anything you want. You annotate most things.  Its up the the framework to decide what to do with the information you place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *difference* depends on the annotation and how it is used. For example, in Spring you can use the `@Controller` annotation only on a class. This tells Spring that the class is a controller.

As far as methods are concerned, `@RequestMapping` is an annotation that goes on a method. For properties, you can have validation annotations like `@NotNull` (in Hibernate validator).

Annotations are definitely not casual; they carry meaning and can affect the way the code behaves.

From the [Java documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) regarding annotations:

> Annotations provide data about a
>   program that is not part of the
>   program itself. They have no direct
>   effect on the operation of the code
>   they annotate.
>
> Annotations have a number of uses,
>   among them:
>
> - Information for the compiler — Annotations can be used by the
>     compiler to detect errors or suppress
>     warnings.
> - Compiler-time and deployment-time processing — Software tools can
>     process annotation information to
>     generate code, XML files, and so
>     forth.
> - Runtime processing — Some annotations are available to be
>     examined at runtime.
>
> Annotations can be applied to a
>   program's declarations of classes,
>   fields, methods, and other program
>   elements.

You can specify what an annotation can annotate by specifying the the elements (using a `@Target` annotation) when you define your own annotation.

Comment: My question is born, working with Hibernate search. I saw annotation,  sometimes on the methods and sometimes on field. My coworker said that the "convention" is on the method... But I'm not sure of this...

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the code that interprets the annotations. It can of course make a difference, but the annotations you are talking about are probably meant to annotate a "property", which is something that technically *does not exist* in Java.

Java has fields and methods, but these are used to simulate properties under the "Java Bean" conventions, i.e. you have a public `setX()` and a `getX()` method that often (but not always) write and read a private field `x`. They're tied together via a naming condition, not a language mechanism.

Because of that, most frameworks that use annotations for such properties (e.g. for persistence mapping or dependency injection) are flexible and allow you to annotate either the field or the get or set method.